# Cannot see index.php on localhost, Firefox prompts to open file in editor

Tags: apache-http-server, linux-mint, webserver, lamp

I have a small index.php that I created by following a tutorial on [the official PHP site](http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.firstpage.php) but cannot see it on localhost.

I formatted my drive, reinstalled Linux Mint, Apache2, PHP5 and MariaDB. No files have been tampered with.

After creating and running index.php from my Bluefish editor, Firefox opens a new tab and immediately prompts me asking if Firefox should open index.php with Bluefish editor. I think my Apache2 isn't configured right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The comments thread had a bunch of useful troubleshooting tips but it turned out the issue was with the browser. I recommend having a spare, 'pristine' browser for testing, so if your mimetypes are messed up, you can still check. The OP installed opera and it worked, when firefox didn't. In his shoes, I might consider purging firefox - which eliminates all config files (though resetting it may work) and reinstalling.

Other things worth testing for (Via comments made by myself, [agtoever](https://superuser.com/users/352717/agtoever) and [Dragonlord](https://superuser.com/users/73918/dragonlord))

- Check if apache is running with `sudo service apache2 status`
- Check package installs `sudo apt-get install php5 libapache2-mod-php5` to make sure apache and the apache/php module is installed. If they are freshly installed, make sure apache is restarted with `sudo service apache2 restart`
- Make sure `mod_php5` is set up to load when Apache is started. There should be a file in `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled` called `php5.load` with the text `LoadModule php5_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so` ([*source*](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/loadmodule-php5_module-modules-libphp5-so-904468/#post4479560)). If not, you might want to add this line to `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`:

  ```
  LoadModule php5_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so
  ```
- Check file permissions.
- `telnet 127.0.0.1 80` to do an oldschool web server test.After some output, type "GET" and enter. Also try this with "GET index.php". This checks if apache2 actually serves your processed php file
- Check the settings in Firefox and Bluefish. In bluefish go to Edit, Preferences, External Programs. Under Browsers, Mozilla & Opera's command should read: "firefox %s". In Firefox, go to Help, Troubleshooting Information, Profile Directory: Show Folder. Try to delete the mimeTypes.rdf file in the Firefox Profile Folder.

Comment: I want to thank all of you so very much for helping me find a solution to my issue. Who would have ever thought it would be my Firefox browser that I just installed only a couple hours earlier after formatting my drive? You guys are great! Thanks a million =)

Comment: np. I'd like to add, CWed since most of this answer belongs to the other awesome users who helped out.

Comment: @Landslyde great you found an answer! Happy I could have helped!

Answer (score 3):

My problem was that I was running the PHP files from Bluefish, which sent them to Firefox and appeared in the URL bar as file:///var/www/html/index.php. This is incorrect for PHP files to run on the local machine. Instead, the URL should've read: localhost/index.php. This reflects my index.php file stored in /var/www/html. This is the only way on the local machine that the PHP interpreter will work. I hope this helps someone on down the road.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the above answers if you go into bluefish preferences and change firefox to "firefox -remote 'openURL(%p)' || firefox localhost/'%n'&" or make a new one called TestFox with that and set it to default if you want to be safe. It should then work like you want.